# How can a page frame be assigned to more than one process?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel

I'm reading the book "Understanding the linux kernel", and this is what it says about the `__count` field of the page descriptor (`struct page`) :

> _count:
>
> A usage reference counter for the page. If it is set to - 1, the corresponding page
>   frame is free and can be assigned to any process or to the kernel itself. If it is set
>   to a value greater than or equal to 0, the page frame is assigned to **one or more
>   processes** or is used to store some kernel data structures. The page_count() func-
>   tion returns the value of the _count field increased by one, that is, the number of
>   users of the page.

My question is, if the same page is assigned to two processes, can't one process access memory assigned to the other by just decrementing/incrementing the linear address by a value smaller than `PAGE_SIZE`?

Comment: Yes one process can access memory of another process if both have some virtual page mapped to the same physical page. That's the point of mapping a physical page to more than one process --- so that they can share memory.

Comment: @n.m. So `__count` will be greater than 1 only if the processes are using shared memory?

Comment: or you can look at it the other way: shared memory is implemented by mapping the same physical page to multiple virtual pages in different processes.

Comment: I don't know if it is "if and only if". There might be other cases, not sure.

Comment: Also, executable code (and other read-only section) from runnable files (executables and shared objects) is usually shared between all processes that use them.

Comment: This also happens when both processes use same code (an executable program or a shared library).